# RestKit: Knowing whether the request was a POST or PUT in didLoadObjects

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

Is there a way to tell in `- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects` whether my request to the server was a POST or PUT?

I need to respond differently depending on what HTTP verb was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get that by checking the RKRequest object using:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects{

    RKRequest *request = [objectLoader.response request];
    NSLog(@"Got %@ method",[request method]);

}
```

You can get more info checking [this link](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKRequest.html#//api/name/method)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!